Is there a better way than `setkeycodes` to add support for the laptop Fn key?
I just got a new laptop (https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=03e388324a), MSI Prestige 16 AI Studio B1VGG.
The laptop's keyboard lacks Home/End/PageUp/PageDown keys, so I'd like to map Fn+Left/Right/Up/Down to Home/End/PageUp/PageDown. On Windows, I was able to do this with AutoHotkey (Fn has scancode 140 there).
On Linux, however, the Fn key on this laptop does not trigger a key event by default.
When I press the Fn key, the following gets appended to dmesg:
atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xc0 on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e040 <keycode>' to make it known.
msi_wmi: Unknown event received

If I then run the following command, the Fn key becomes recognized by atkbd:
sudo setkeycodes 0xc0 0x1d0


0x1d0 is KEY_FN in Linux's input-event-codes.h.
msi_wmi still complains but that's fine I guess.

After running the setkeycodes, I can successfully map Fn+Arrow keys using the excellent Input Remapper (my config).
However, I need to run setkeycodes every time on boot, which seems a bit hackish.

Is there a better way than setkeycodes make Linux recognize the Fn key automatically? E.g. some kind of config file.
Can something be done so that this works for all the Linux users of this laptop out-of-the box?

